# calculate fama french factors in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, finance

I am trying to calculate the fama french factors in r.
after several days of sweat and despair I managed to calculate the returns of the 6 respective portfolios...only to find a problem i just dont seem to be able to solve.

my data approximately looks like this, this is just a simplified data set to illustrate my problem:

```
> TestX = data.table(Group = c("SM", "SM", "SM", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SL", "SL", "SL"), Date= as.Date(c("1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30", "1995-07-30")), Code= c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9"), SMRet = c(2,3,3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SHRet = c(NA, NA, NA, 5,5,5, NA, NA, NA), SLRet = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0,1,2) )
> TestX
   Group       Date Code SMRet SHRet SLRet
1:    SM 1995-07-30   C1     2    NA    NA
2:    SM 1995-07-30   C2     3    NA    NA
3:    SM 1995-07-30   C3     3    NA    NA
4:    SH 1995-07-30   C4    NA     5    NA
5:    SH 1995-07-30   C5    NA     5    NA
6:    SH 1995-07-30   C6    NA     5    NA
7:    SL 1995-07-30   C7    NA    NA     0
8:    SL 1995-07-30   C8    NA    NA     1
9:    SL 1995-07-30   C9    NA    NA     2
```

Group gives the group (SmallMedium, SmallHigh, SmallLow, I have the other groups in the real data.table). Code gives the respective company codes etc.
what I want to do is create a new column with the respective factors.
for that I need to do the following calculation:
`(Smret+SHret+SLret)/3`, but how can I do that?

```
TestX[, Factor := (SMRet+SHRet+SLRet)/3, by = Date]
```

didnt work, I only got NAs everywhere.

```
  Group       Date Code SMRet SHRet SLRet Factor
1:    SM 1995-07-30   C1     2    NA    NA     NA
2:    SM 1995-07-30   C2     3    NA    NA     NA
3:    SM 1995-07-30   C3     3    NA    NA     NA
4:    SH 1995-07-30   C4    NA     5    NA     NA
5:    SH 1995-07-30   C5    NA     5    NA     NA
6:    SH 1995-07-30   C6    NA     5    NA     NA
7:    SL 1995-07-30   C7    NA    NA     0     NA
8:    SL 1995-07-30   C8    NA    NA     1     NA
9:    SL 1995-07-30   C9    NA    NA     2     NA
```

I also need to group by date. the real data.table has 402 other months.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is a better data.table to illustrate my problem

```
TestX = data.table(Group = c("SM", "SM", "SH", "SH", "SL", "SL", "SM", "SM", "SH", "SH", "SL", "SL"), Date= as.Date(c("1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-07-30","1995-08-30","1995-08-30", "1995-08-30", "1995-08-30","1995-08-30","1995-08-30")), Code= c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "c10", "c11", "12"), SMRet = c(2,3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA), SHRet = c(NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA), SLRet = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1, NA,NA,NA, NA, 2,3))
> TestX

        Group       Date Code SMRet SHRet SLRet
     1:    SM 1995-07-30   C1     2    NA    NA
     2:    SM 1995-07-30   C2     3    NA    NA
     3:    SH 1995-07-30   C3    NA     5    NA
     4:    SH 1995-07-30   C4    NA     5    NA
     5:    SL 1995-07-30   C5    NA    NA     0
     6:    SL 1995-07-30   C6    NA    NA     1
     7:    SM 1995-08-30   C7     4    NA    NA
     8:    SM 1995-08-30   C8     5    NA    NA
     9:    SH 1995-08-30   C9    NA     3    NA
    10:    SH 1995-08-30  c10    NA     4    NA
    11:    SL 1995-08-30  c11    NA    NA     2
    12:    SL 1995-08-30   12    NA    NA     3
```

and this is the desired result:

```
    Group       Date Code SMRet SHRet SLRet   Factor
 1:    SM 1995-07-30   C1     2    NA    NA 5.333333
 2:    SM 1995-07-30   C2     3    NA    NA 5.333333
 3:    SH 1995-07-30   C3    NA     5    NA 5.333333
 4:    SH 1995-07-30   C4    NA     5    NA 5.333333
 5:    SL 1995-07-30   C5    NA    NA     0 5.333333
 6:    SL 1995-07-30   C6    NA    NA     1 5.333333
 7:    SM 1995-08-30   C7     4    NA    NA 7.000000
 8:    SM 1995-08-30   C8     5    NA    NA 7.000000
 9:    SH 1995-08-30   C9    NA     3    NA 7.000000
10:    SH 1995-08-30  c10    NA     4    NA 7.000000
11:    SL 1995-08-30  c11    NA    NA     2 7.000000
12:    SL 1995-08-30   12    NA    NA     3 7.000000
```

so: for each month:(SMRet+ShRet+SLRet)/3

Comment: sorry, I should have created a better data.table to illustrate my problem. the issue is: my real data.table is much longer. for every month I have data like this and I need to calculate monthly factors, so SMRet of 1995 july 30 should be computed with SHret of 1995 july 30 and SLret of 1995 july 30, not with the other dates. clearer now?

Comment: I will add a bigger data.table and my expected result, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I just posted an updated version. sorry for the wait and bother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to calculate the fama french factors in R:

```
TestX[ , newvar := sum(SMRet, SHRet, SLRet, na.rm=TRUE)/3, by=Date]
```

Comment: thank you, I shouldnt ask questions at 3 am in the morning (german time), totally messed up my question. but with your help I found a solution which was quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `tidyverse` is a convenient  package for this task, yet it may be not as fast as `data.table`. you can easily calculate by group with `group_by()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
TestX %>% 
    gather("GP", "value", -Group,-Code, -Date) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>% # gather the 3 columns into 1, and then compute
    arrange(Date,Group, Code) %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>% # group before compute the results, you can also group by Code
    mutate(Factor = sum(value)/3)

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   Date [2]
  Group Date       Code  GP    value Factor
  <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 SH    1995-07-30 C3    SHRet     5   5.33
 2 SH    1995-07-30 C4    SHRet     5   5.33
 3 SL    1995-07-30 C5    SLRet     0   5.33
 4 SL    1995-07-30 C6    SLRet     1   5.33
 5 SM    1995-07-30 C1    SMRet     2   5.33
 6 SM    1995-07-30 C2    SMRet     3   5.33
 7 SH    1995-08-30 c10   SHRet     4   7
 8 SH    1995-08-30 C9    SHRet     3   7
 9 SL    1995-08-30 12    SLRet     3   7
10 SL    1995-08-30 c11   SLRet     2   7
11 SM    1995-08-30 C7    SMRet     4   7
12 SM    1995-08-30 C8    SMRet     5   7
```